# Manually adding annotations?

Tags: java, android, junit, annotations, junit4

Don't ask why (I promise I need to do this), I need to create an annotation that is just a pass-through to apply the @Test annotation to methods.  For example:

```
@MyTestAnnotation
public void testMyStuff() {
    ....
}
```

And then I just need to write a MyTestAnnotation class to apply @Test to the method.  I feel like there's a way to do this, but I just don't know enough about how Java annotations work to write this code.  For example, there are easy way to do things like this in Python.

Comment: I'm not certain this is doable.

Answer (score 1):

> Don't ask why (I promise I need to do this)

It's very possible that there's a better solution to your [real problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). For example, if you're trying to get JUnit to run a set of methods that aren't annotated then you could create a subclass and use a [custom runner](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/RunWith.html), or [generate a `TestSuite` at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11932146/733345).

Answer (score 0):

Relates to this:

[Adding Java Annotations at Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635108/adding-java-annotations-at-runtime)

As they say, not possible in a straight way.