# Use field access in JAXB without annotations

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have some objects I want to marshal using JAXB. Using `@XmlRootElement` and `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` it’s easy. However, I would much prefer not to change the class in question since the code in question is outside of my responsibility and I need to marshal it only for debugging purposes.

Using the article [JAXB - No Annotations Required](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-no-annotations-required.html) I got rid of the `@XmlRootElement`, but how can I configure the field access programmatically? Is there any standard way?

Comment: I am not sure if this will work, but i think you can add the annotation  `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` at runtime using Java reflection. http://stackoverflow.com/a/30287201/6371459. Make a recursive method for the object to marshall and apply also to inner objects (exclude java basic objects in `java.lang`)

Comment: This may work, yes. But it’s incredibly hacky. I don’t have the energy to try this out. I managed so sneak in a package-level annotation which was good enough for my special case (all classes are in the same package, and all require the same XML accessor type).

Comment: Jajajaja, sure It would be a risky solution

Comment: @Mickael , have you got solution for this

Comment: No, @VijayGupta, at the time, I found the work-around, and I didn’t have that specific problem since.