# Java add annotation to class based on condition

Tags: java, annotations

I was wondering if it is possible to add an annotation to a Java class based on a condition.

For example, suppose I have two standard classes (`Foo` and `Bar`) and an abstract one (`AbstractGeneric`). Can I add an annotation to `AbstractGeneric` just if `Foo` extends it?

I searched and just found some people suggesting using Adapter, but I never used it. If it is possible, could someone give me a simple example on how to implement that?

Comment: why can't you just use the annotation on the `Foo` class?

Comment: @JackFlamp because if `Bar` extends `AbstractGeneric`, I should use a different annotation.

Comment: if it is a custom annotation you can use an attribute and set different values to it and change behaviour based on that value.. would that work?

Comment: it would I believe, but I can't change the annotation, once it is from a core library. Is it possible to add an annotation to a classe before create a new instance of it?

Comment: I guess [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1635122/3959856) is what you have looked at. like he says, you can't add it dynamically. could there be a totally different solution to the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: yes, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I would google the adapter pattern and read the examples. it is not too advanded.

Comment: thank you, I'm trying it right now.

Comment: It sounds like you would be better off using an abstract method than an annotation.