# Annotate inherited fields in anonymous class in runtime

Tags: java, reflection

Lets suppose i have a class:

```
public class Foo {

    int a;
    int b;

}
```

And i'm creating an object of anonymous class. The question is that is it technically possibile to set annotation on fields **a** and **b** like below but **in run time**?

```
Foo anonymous = new Foo() {
    @Annotation
    int a;
    @Annotation
    int b;

}
```

Comment: Your current code declares *separate* fields which *hide* ones inherited from superclass. Regarding "is that is it technically possibile to set annotation .. at runtime" maybe [Adding Java Annotations at Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1635108) will help.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by setting annotations at runtime? If you are trying to use a framework feature that uses annotations, there are often ways to use the same feature programmatically.

Comment: @kapex yes, but the problem is that i dont know which class i will get on input in order to return object with annotated fields of superclass

Comment: @kapex i want to decide what fields i want to serialize and which not, to achive it programmatically means to set transient key word on a field in runtime what seems to me less achievable than annotating fields in runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who still search an answer for the question you will find it here:
[Adding Java Annotations at Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1635108)