# Setting Test annotation dynamically

Tags: java, testing, testng

I want to create a data-driven framework, where the test will execute based on data in excel.

Currently when I execute the tests, all results under one testName only.

What I am looking for is for every iteration should be treated as separate test.

Comment: Is each `@Test` in a different class?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to add an annotation to an existing class at runtime; see [Adding Java Annotations at Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635108/adding-java-annotations-at-runtime).  That Q&A suggests using `Proxy` to or an adapter to deal with this, but I don't think that approach will work for TestNG testing.

You probably need to take a different approach.  [Section 5.14](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng-programmatically) of the TestNG documentation has an example that shows how to run the tests in a test class programmatically:

> ```
> TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
> TestNG testng = new TestNG();
> testng.setTestClasses(new Class[] { Run2.class });
> testng.addListener(tla);
> testng.run();
> ```
>
> This example creates a `TestNG` object and runs the test class Run2. It
>   also adds a `TestListener`. You can either use the adapter class
>   `org.testng.TestListenerAdapter` or implement `org.testng.ITestListener`
>   yourself. This interface contains various callback methods that let
>   you keep track of when a test starts, succeeds, fails, etc...

Then [Section 5.17](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#methodinterceptors) explains how to use a method interceptor to massage the list of methods to be called.  Finally [Section 5.18](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-listeners) explains various ways to tell TestNG to use listeners such as a method interceptor.

If you combine these with code for extracting data from your Excel spreadsheet and run the relevant test classes or test methods programmatically.