# SpringFox Swagger - Hide Certain Fields of a POJO in Java

Tags: java, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, springfox

I have a POJO model that contains lots of fields.  When we generate OpenApi Swagger docs for external users, we only want to expose a subset of the fields.  Is there a way to do that?  We don't want to change the POJO to add `@ApiModelProperty` for each field.

Comment: I don't know an easier way then to write it yourself, after `javac` is done, like [this may be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635108/adding-java-annotations-at-runtime), but it will not be easy

Comment: have you considered facading the pojo's with boundary classes, exposing only the fields which are used in the request?