# Is there a way to add an annotation to a class at runtime with Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, reflection, dapr

Due to a third-party library requirement I have to do some finagling with annotations.

Using Kotlin, is there a way to dynamically add an annotation to class metadata at runtime like you can in Java?

e.g. something like:

```
clazz.annotations.set(idx, myAnnotation)
```

Comment: What is the third-party library, and what kind of annotations do you need to add?

Comment: In this case, it's the Dapr Java SDK. It registers actors by name, by default - the class name (non FQ).  The Dapr actor runtime makes these addressable by the name it extracts within a k8s cluster. The problem is, I want to have different actor versions running on the cluster - so I'm attempting to use Dapr's annotation: `@ActorType` which has a name attribute. 

I'm attempting to set that name attribute on the actors that are being registered at runtime based on an environment variable/prefix to provide that isolation.

Comment: Should actually be possible, at least based on this response: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30287201/2135888